# What is the maximum number of iSCSI connections that Server 2012 R2 can initiate?

Tags: iscsi, windows-server-2012-r2

I found online that Server 2008 R2 host can only initiate a maximum of 255 iSCSI connections, and that it was a hard limit within the OS itself.

Does this same restriction apply to Server 2012 R2?

To be specific, I am asking how many connections can be initiated from Server 2012 R2 to another target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft hasn't released any documentation on the [iSCSI target server scalability limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659435.aspx) for Server 2012 R2 because they're the same as Server 2012.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From this [thread on TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67d060e0-546b-433d-a38b-ee45b79b2812/lun-limit-with-iscsi-2012-r2?forum=winserverfiles) is looks like the 255 limit is still present in 2012 R2.

> I have a use case where I want to address lots of iSCSI LUNs on a 2012 R2 machine. I seem to have hit a limit of 255 mounted iSCSI volumes.

Comment: I'm asking the reverse. I want to know how many connections it can initiate, not how many it can host as a target.